# Is there a way to write logs to a file without appending the timestamp using fluentd?

Tags: fluentd

I intend to write some logs to a file called `output.log` using fluentd. Im using this configuration

```
<match foo.*>
        @type file
        path /var/log/output
        path_suffix .log
        append true
        <buffer>
          flush_mode interval
          flush_interval 1m
        </buffer>
        format json
      </match>
```

However fluentd is appending timestamps to the output file making it output..log. Is there a workaround to make this file output.log?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation. Seems like you can define custom log formats. ( https://docs.fluentd.org/v/0.12/articles/common-log-formats )

```
format /^\[[^ ]* \] \[(?<level>[^\]]*)\] \[pid (?<pid>[^\]]*)\] \[client (?<client>[^\]]*)\] (?<message>.*)$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm coming in late but it might still serve future readers - the following could help: https://docs.fluentd.org/configuration/buffer-section#empty-keys:

So:

```
  <store>
    @type file
    path .../filename
    append true
    <buffer []>
      flush_mode immediate # that's what I wanted for testing
      # ...
    </buffer>
  </store>
```

Creates file named `.../filename.log`